# Reset /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches to default value 0

Tags: linux, unix, caching, server, debian

Recently I tried to empty the buffers cache on a Debian webserver. The command I used was:

`free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free`

So far so good, running `cat /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` prints a value of 3.

When I try to reset the value to 0 with `sync && echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, this error shows:

> `bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument`

Which is due to `drop_caches` being a command, not a variable to be set. I found [this](https://duopetalflower.blogspot.com/2009/09/clearing-cache-memory-in-linux-using.html?showComment=1306571736678#c2138239868115542620):

`sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3`

It immediately clears the pagecache, dentries and inodes and clears again only if you call `sysctl -w` again, there is no need to apparently set it back to 0 in an explicit manner. The command `sysctl` is not natively supported on Debian so I'm looking for an alternative command, more precisely:

**How to reset drop_caches or immediately empty the cache to reset the value to 0?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values 1-3 are just one time trigger for action. There is no value 0.

sysctl is in package procps .

`apt install procps`

Comment: Thanks @lbor for the reply. So setting any value 1-3 will just trigger the action to clear the cache once, correct? I'm aware that `sysctl` has to be installed separately which is why I asked for an alternate command already installed which seems to be writing the value directly into the `drop_caches` file. Will `sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=0` work?

Comment: You can use only values 1,2 and 3. There is no value 0. You only start trigger which clear cache and cache will start caching immediately again.

Comment: For more info you should Check https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt

Answer (score 0):

> To disable them, echo 4 (bit 2) into drop_caches.

from https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt